# No Sound from Mac Mini after OS X Server Reinstall

Tags: macos, mac, audio

I had to reinstall OS X Lion Server 10.7 on my Mac mini (late 2011) due to partition and boot record corruption. Since reinstalling, I have not have sound. The only sound device that shows under Utilities > Sound is "Internal Speaker". Previously, "Headphones" also appeared. I have a Harman Kardon Soundsticks 2.1 sound system. It has only one sound connector. I always plugged it into the green port on the mini. It worked fine. Since reinstalling I have no sound at all. Any ideas out there? Solutions? I've been through the Cmd-P-R deal, reinstalled OS X Lion Server - all to no avail.

Comment: Are there any sound devices in System Preferences>Sound?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `~/Library/Preferences` and trash your `com.apple.systemsound.plist file`. Drag it right into the trash. Empty trash and restart your Mac.

A new plist file will generate automatically, look for the speaker/sound icon in your Finder menu. If that doesn't resolve the issue, try <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> again during reboot and make sure you hear the Apple chime at least two times for a full recycle.