# Mac Mini: No sound except for startup chime

Tags: macos, audio, mac-mini, speakers

I have a Mac Mini (mid 2010) and out of nowhere the sound has completely stopped working, the only exception to this is the startup chime when turning on the machine.

I have already checked to see if I just muted the sound, that the internal speakers are selected in system preferences, reset the PRAM, restarted the computer, and wiggled a jack inside of the headphone jack hole.

I have no idea what is going on with the sound! I know the speakers are not broken because the startup chime works, also I've tried using external speakers but those don't solve anything either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long, long time without any sound on my computer, I finally fixed the problem! First I booted the mac into recovery mode by restarting it while holding **⌘ + R**. Then I simply chose **Reinstall OS X** from the *OS X Utilities* window. Then after a while of installing, the machine worked good as new!

Hopefully this helps anybody with the same problem in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Try this
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54800/210364

I had the same problem, and these steps helped:

Reboot your mac holding Command + Option + P + R until you hear at least two startup chimes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly this did not work :(