# Why does my Mac mini (2018) have no startup sound?

Tags: audio, mac-mini, startup, sound-volume

My Mac mini (2018) has a speaker that works well for playing music and making user interface sound effects. But I do not hear a startup chime when booting the machine.

In other words, I have the exact opposite problem of this Question, [*Mac Mini: No sound except for startup chime*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260800/17907)

Is there a way to restore the traditional startup sound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has removed the startup chime from all the Mac models starting from Late 2016.

- [About Mac startup tones](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202768)

> Mac models from early 2016 and earlier make a chime sound when they start up. Mac models from late 2016 and newer don't have a startup chime, with the exception of MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017).

Answer (score 1):

See [this TidBITS article](https://tidbits.com/2020/02/24/tipbits-enable-the-startup-chime-on-new-macs/).

Basically, on some systems, you can re-enable the startup chime with this Terminal command:

```
sudo nvram BootAudio=%01
```

On later systems, this might work:

```
sudo nvram StartupMute=%00
```